# настройка htaccess url

Tags: .htaccess, маршрутизация

Как сделать чтобы при открытии
http://site.ru/catalog/heroes
Открывалось то же самое что и:
http://site.ru/catalog/?cat=heroes
?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/catalog/([^/]*)/$   /catalog/?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

тут в переменную ?cat=$1 будет подставляться любое значение указанное в ([^/]*), L - означает что после этой записи чтение .htaccess будет закончено, а QSA разрешит непосредственно передачу любых других данных (как пост так и гет) по заданному url

Comment: Что то не получается( Возможно потому что в htaccess уже есть запись: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Что именно, возможно есть правило подходящее под заданное с атрибутом L

Comment: сейчас при переходе на /catalog/giro/ выводит ошибка 404

Comment: Возможно у вас парсится урл и разбирается что за категория? Мало информации что бы качественно ответить

Comment: что означает RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] ?

Comment: Что все возможные варианты будут перенаправлены на индекс.пхп

Comment: http://site.ru/catalog как тогда эта ссылка будет для скрипта видится?

Comment: По стандартной логике

Comment: Это как?)) catalog будет гет параметр? или пост? как скрипт его видит?

Comment: Нет, в параметр переведутся следующая часть урл, которая в правиле предоставлена регулярным выражением, просто /catalog/ пройдет не по этому правилу так как нет следующей части урл